# WinForms C# Add PrinterSetting Values before show PrintDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, printdialog

I want to add all PrinterSetting values before show PrintDialog from WinForms. Exampale: I want to set copies = 4 :

```
PrintDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies = 4;
DialogResult result = PrintDialog.ShowDialog();
```

But copies showed still be 1. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Do so by assigning PrintSettings to an instance of PrintDialog.

```
using (var printDialog = new PrintDialog())
{
    var printSettings = new PrinterSettings {Copies = 4};
    printDialog.PrinterSettings = printSettings;
    printDialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

This results in the following dialog.
[image]

Comment: I've added an image to show that the above solution is working for me.

Comment: I've tried your code, but my printDialog variable is a global variable. So It declared before. the copies values still be 1.

Comment: Then can you not just `Copies = COPY_COUNT`? Possibly update your question with further example code?